# Can we have an option about placement of the HTML answer while editing an answer?

Tags: feature-request, markdown-rendering

The Stack Overflow answer text-area is reasonably good, but when I am writing a moderately sized answer (and more importantly, reviewing it for correctness and formatting), at times it is cumbersome that the final rendered HTML is below the markdown that I am providing. This is especially true if the answer contains code snippets.

Is it worth having an option to place the two views side-by-side? Does anyone see have this problem? How do you solve it?

Comment: I remember that there's a FR somewhere about this.

Comment: There is definitely a user script or browser extension for this. Just search around.

Comment: There's already a few feature requests for this, see [The Discourse layout for side-by-side Markdown preview](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253112), [Preview on the right please, optionally?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53484), [Putting the edit box and the markdown box side by side](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249679), and [a userscript which does this](http://stackapps.com/questions/6461/side-by-side-editing).